# How to install MSpec BDD Framework?

Tags: resharper, testing, bdd, mspec

Does anyone know if there is an MSpec installer with R# and/or TestDriven.NET support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official installer for MSpec BDD Framework.
I have released it for my own and it is available on my blog. It is able to integrate MSpec 0.3 with Resharper 4.1, 4.5, 5.0 and TestDriven.NET so it is what you need.

[Link to MSpec BDD Framework installer](http://marcinobel.com/index.php/mspec-bdd-installer/)

Answer (score 4):

Even better if you have the latest version of TestDriven.NET (>=2.24): Just drop MSpec's TestDriven.NET runner assembly (Machine.Specifications.TDNetRunner.dll) and the Machine.Specifications.dll.tdnet file in the project folder containing the Machine.Specifications.dll assembly and MSpec will work automagically. No installation needed.